# No delete option when right clicking on a class inside models in asp.net core mvc project in visual studio 2022

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2022

After creating a class inside models in asp.net core mvc app, I tried to delete that class by right clicking on class name in solution explorer but there is no delete option or rename option. I'm using visual studio 2022.

Here is  the screenshot when right click on model class name:
https://i.postimg.cc/s2NSLW0M/Untitled.png

Comment: Where exactly are you searching for that option? Did you try right-clicking the file in the Solution Explorer window?

Comment: I will add screeshot. Yes i tried in the solution explorer

Comment: This is the screenshot when I right click in solution explorer (shows no delete option) https://i.postimg.cc/s2NSLW0M/Untitled.png

Comment: Is this [tag:Visual-Studio-2022] that you are asking about or [tag:visual-studio-code].  You worded it _Visual Studio Code 2022_

Comment: It's visual studio 2022...I corrected it.

Answer (score 2):

The option to delete or rename a class is not available while the web application is running. After  stopping the application the options are available.

Answer (score 1):

It can be because you are running the project.
Stop running the project with **Shift + F5**